# How to convert timestamp to date?

Tags: mysql, time

How to convert this time `1329944650` to this time `2011-1-2` using MySQL

I just want to know how to change mktime to this date `(2011-01-2)` using MySQL.

Comment: Any evidence of prior research at all? Did you even _load_ the MySQL manual?

Comment: yes i already call this event but i didn't understand what should i try that why i put this Question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert unix timestamp into human readable format mysql has built-in function FROM_UNIXTIME() it takes 2 parameters first is the timestamp that you want to convert and the second one is the format in which you want to convert in your case this should be

```
FROM_UNIXTIME('1329944650', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Answer (score 6):

Try with [`FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp,format)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(1329944650, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 3):

FROM_UNIXTIME and DATE function.

```
select DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME('1329944650'))
```

---

```
mysql> select DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME('1329944650'));
+-----------------------------------+
| DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME('1329944650')) |
+-----------------------------------+
| 2012-02-23                        |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

I want this format and i got my answer thank you all of us

`SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1329944650, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') AS created_date`